# Best practice for setting a List<T> to Null

Tags: c#, list

Before the question, my concern is that items within a list are not set to null if the list itself is set to null...therefore leaving behind some unclean references.

Let's say I have a simple list of People

```
public class Person
{
  string Name {get;set;}
  string Title {get;set;}
  int ID {get;set;}
};
```

Now I populate that list somehow

```
public List<Person> GetMeSomePeople()
{
   Person newPersonA = new Person
   {
     Name = "Michael",
     Title = "C# Code Guy",
     ID = 1
   };
   //... add more people

   List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
   People.Add(newPersonA);
   //...add more people to list

   return People;
}
```

And here is the question...now I want to nullify this list.

Is the best practice to iterate through the list and set each object to null?

Or clear?

```
People.Clear();
```

Or just set the list to be null

```
People = null;
```

Lastly, if you have some method that repopulates that list...should the list be nullified correctly before doing so?

```
//Already populated People with 2 Person
People = GetMeSomeMorePeople();
```

Comment: I don't see a error here

Comment: I think you're worrying too much. If there are no more references to an object, then it will be cleaned up eventually by the GC. You don't have to set anything to `null` when you're done using it.

Comment: Garbage collection means not having to worry about such things. Learn to love it. If you need a new list, make a new list. `.Clear()` (with no reassignment) would be appropriate if you have reason to believe you're going to add about as many objects again as you previously had, as you save some allocations on the list not having to grow in the background -- but if you don't know that for sure, it's premature optimization.

Comment: @RufusL and @@Jeroen Mostert great explanation by both of you!

Comment: This is generally only an issue if the list is a field / property of another object with a longer lifetime than you want for the list (which is not very common). Is that the case? In terms of the options you present though - `Clear` is likely the best since it does what it says on the tin. In general usage though, everyone else is right - don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

> Is the best practice to iterate through the list and set each object to null?
>   Or clear?
>   Or just set the list to be null

None of the above.

Just let the list (People) go out of scope 'naturally', or overwrite the variable with a new list.

All the cleanup you have to do: nothing.

> Lastly, if you have some method that repopulates that list...should the list be nullified correctly before doing so?

No.

Garbage collection works on the principle of 'reachability'. As soon as your main reference (People) is overwriten, the previous list instance becomes unreachable. The next round of the GC will collect it. And all items inside, as long as they are not referenced elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to worry about it. The garbage collector will remove all the objects that are no longer used by anyone.

Setting something to `null` "moves" one reference from pointing somewhere (to an instance of an object, like a `List<>` or a `Person`) to pointing to nowhere ("null"). Other references to that object may or may not exist. Once no more references to the object exists (simplified explanation), the object is garbage, and the garbage collector can remove it if it decides to.

Usually, you set something to `null` because you want to make sure the next person reading that "something" sees `null`. Setting something to `null` to "clean up" is usually not necessary.